# How to check PROXY inside Azure VPN is alive/accessible in PAC File

Tags: javascript, azure, proxy, vpn

I have the proxy server running inside Azure,  its accessible when VPN connection is alive.  However the Automatic Proxy Config file (PAC file) needs to detect somehow that VPN connection is turned ON, otherwise browser does not work (if VPN is turned off.)

So I want to verify my VM  PROXY is online and responsive inside the Automatic proxy config PAC file,  it seems IsResolvable() is not working for this purpose?  Any other functions to use  to detect I am inside VPN where proxy lives?   Is there e.g. some DNS names that exist inside Azure VPN namerange that I can test with the standard isResolvable() function?

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    PROXY = "PROXY 192.168.1.1:88"

   if (! isResolvable ("192.168.1.1"){
     return "DIRECT";
   }

       return PROXY;

}
```

Comment: `isResolvable` tries to resolve a hostname using DNS lookup. It will return true if it was successful, regardless of if the proxy server is responsive or not.

Comment: Can you tag the libraries you're using, or is this a native browser api?

Comment: there are no libraries, just universal PAC file format

Comment: Another solution would be to make this check by comparing local IP, but for some reason local IP was wrong with myIpAddress()